# Specify the assets output directory when building in development mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, assets, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm using the Vue CLI to build my application into one of my existing php projects. In case to work with generated files in php, I need to move the assets to the `../public/assets/` directory. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work in development environment (production mode works just fine, but I'd really need to test the integration of vue in the php app).

Am I doing something wrong or is it a known restriction?

Here's the config:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    outputDir: '../public',
    assetsDir: './assets',
    indexPath: './views/index.html'
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of HMR in development mode this is not yet possible to implement. Here's the [reference to the communication](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/moving-javascript-files-to-assetsdir-directory-when-not-production/) on Vue.js' forum.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you can just copy the `assets` into your `public/assets` folder and reference them via absolute path.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

> Static assets can be handled in two different ways:
>
> - Imported in JavaScript or referenced in templates/CSS via relative paths. Such references will be handled by webpack.
> - Placed in the public directory and referenced via absolute paths. These assets will simply be copied and not go through webpack.